# UE4: Different Details Panels of Component when added through C++ or Blueprint

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am wondering why the details panel of a component is different depending on wether it is added through C++ or Blueprint. I would prefer the Blueprint one, but would like to add the components through C++.

This is how I add the component in C++

```
.h file:

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    class USphereComponent* SphereComponent;

.cpp file:

SphereComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("Sphere Component"));
```

Anyone got an Idea what I am doing wrong or is that by design? If that is by design, how can I make a better details panel. Example: The Transform window is way better to work with, when it looks how in the blueprint example.

**C++ Component:**

[image: C++ Component]

*Blueprint Component:*

[image: Blueprint Component]

Comment: haven't used UE at all but similar things only happened with me when using completely different classes of objects in other projects... try to find out what the blueprint defines the sphere as and that should work for other objects you add in the future as well. Looked a bit at the documentation and it appears the Blueprint adds an actor (as opposed to presumably component that you add in C++)...

Answer (score 0):

edit: solved it. You need to change the UProperty tag from EditAnywhere to VisibleAnywhere. Dont worry you will still be able to edit it! It seems counter intuitive, because it is somewhat. it's analogous to the const pointer/pointer to const distinction in c++. With UObject properties, the property is actually a pointer/reference, so being able to edit the property is taken to mean you can modify the reference - assign a completely different object to the property. Visible means you can't do that, but you can access the referenced object, and if its own properties are editable, then you can still edit them.